# How to add multiple conditional classes while migrating Vue to React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js

While migrating vue component to React, i am not able to understand that how can i apply those multiple classes in same div tag.

**In Vue,**

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="m in Menus" @click="moveMenu(m)" class="primaryClass"
   :class="{'ur-primay__selected':selectedMenu(m)}"> // selectedMenu() is a method
   {{m.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

My query is how can i apply this additional non-prop class attribute adding into the tag in React?

I have tried using template literal to add the classes but not able to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`classnames` utility](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) serves the same purpose in React and accepts an input that is similar to [Vue class bindings](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html#binding-html-classes) and allows for a mix of strings, arrays and objects.

In Vue:

```
<li :class="['primaryClass', {'ur-primay__selected': selectedMenu(m)}]">
```

In React, an array can be flattened because it's possible to provide multiple arguments to the helper:

```
<li className={classnames('primaryClass', {'ur-primay__selected': selectedMenu(m)})}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using string template with backticks ***``***:

```html
<div className={`${selectedMenu(m)?'ur-primay__selected':''}`}>
```